# Undefined symbol in SSLeay.so: OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms

Tags: perl, ssl

I'm trying to do a download of files from a remote host using LWP. Here is a simplified version of my code that reproduces the error:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5.8 -w

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$userAgent->agent("p_o_c");

my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET=>"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2.0/prototype.js");
my $response = $userAgent->request($request);
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
[dev] /home/me > ./tmp/poc.pl
/usr/local/bin/perl5.8: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/ext/perl/5.8.0/lib/site_perl/i686-linux-thread-multi/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms
```

Also, as seen above, I'm running perl 5.8.  I'm running RHEL 6.4 (Santiago).

I've tried downloading a file over http (not https) and that works.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this https download to work? I'm open to other methods too besides LWP, but this seemed like the easiest way.

Comment: perl 5.8. _0_ ?? I thought RHEL 6 comes with 5.10+. 5.8.0 was released in _2002_. I'd suspect the error you're seeing is due to running against a compiled library not matching the openssl version. Alternately, it's due to the really old perl interpreter you're using. Try reinstalling LWP::Protocol::https and dealing with errors encountered (make sure it pases the test suite.) Failing that, try running it against system perl or one of the more current 5.8 revisions.

Comment: What can I say... my organization loves to live in the past ;) I'm going to see if the other modules required for this script can work under a newer perl, because running it under 5.12 causes the error to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oesor mentioned, I am using (not by choice) a *very old* version of Perl. Using a newer version fixed the issue.